# Getting Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.transport.SimpleAxis2Server

Tags: java, linux, apache-axis

I am new to Axis , I am trying to start Axis2 as a Standalone Server using the Standard Binary Distribution package in Linux. I went through this guide: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html

I have downloaded and unpacked the distribution in it's own directory and i have also set environment variables AXIS2_HOME and JAVA_HOME as follows :

`export AXIS2_HOME=/opt/axis2-1.8.2`

`echo $AXIS2_HOME`    returns

`/opt/axis2-1.8.2`

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin`

`echo $JAVA_HOME` returns

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin`

When trying to run **axis2server.sh** which is essentially the script to start the server I get the following prompts :

```
user@serverFoo/opt/axis2-1.8.2/bin$ ./axis2server.sh
 Using AXIS2_HOME: /opt/axis2-1.8.2
 Using JAVA_HOME:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.axis2.transport.SimpleAxis2Server
```

Coming from a JAVA background I understand that it can't find or load the server class, although I can't find any resources in the web pointing to the specific error .

EDIT : I have also added CLASSPATH variable pointing to the AXIS2_HOME/lib directory i.e

`export CLASSPATH=/opt/axis2-1.8.2/lib/*.jar` but still the same .

Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: JAVA_HOME should point to the root of the Java installation directory (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`), not to bin.

Comment: @k314159 no , still the same

Comment: Your command `export CLASSPATH=/opt/axis2-1.8.2/lib/*.jar` doesn't seem right. If there are multiple jar files in that directory, say a.jar and b.jar, then the Linux shell will expand that into the following command `export CLASSPATH=/opt/axis2-1.8.2/lib/a.jar /opt/axis2-1.8.2/lib/b.jar` but the space is not a valid separator. Try the wildcard syntax `export CLASSPATH='/opt/axis2-1.8.2/lib/*'` as specified at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#A1100762 and taking care to put the asterisk in quotes so that the shell doesn't expand it.

Comment: @k314159 when echo $CLASSPATH , i get a full list of all .jar files inside lib directory , so i think setting the classpath worked just fine . Although i will try your idea and let you know. It's the first time i can't find anything similar to my problem . I have also checked system requirements section in official APACHE Axis website and states that JAVA 8 or above will be compatible with the latest AXIS2 distribution . I am using java 8  .

Comment: @k314159 . Still getting the same error , i am so frustrated i  am stuck here for so long. Not even stack overflow can help :)    . I have also tried setting the AXIS2_HOME variable to /opt and /opt/axis2-1.8.2/bin AND also did a fresh installation but without any luck

Comment: I downloaded the same distribution, and looked inside all the jars, and I can confirm there is no such class. It looks as if the distribution is broken, but Axis is such an old system that I doubt there would be many people still working on it and interested in fixing it.

Comment: @k314159  , maybe if i download an older (archived) version of AXIS would do the trick. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6):

Inside the start file `$AXIS2_HOME/bin/axis2server.sh` there is an issue at the end of the file. This occurs because in the lastest versions of Axis2, the class "SimpleAxis2Server" was moved from `transport` to `kernel`.

Just replace:

org.apache.axis2.**transport**.SimpleAxis2Server

with:

org.apache.axis2.**kernel**.SimpleAxis2Server

Enjoy!!

Note: For Windows, edit the `.bat` file instead.

Comment: Hey , little late to the party i have installed axis2.war package as a workaround as i wouldn't find a solution . Thanks , if nessecary i will try your answer . thanks for your time

Comment: I did it and worked!!